# Why are all the questions about upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10 being closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I was trying to decide if I should upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 from my current 12.04 LTS. There are many reviews around the internet regarding the new features of Ubuntu 12.10 and I enjoy some of them, but I wouldn't upgrade if those features were brought to Ubuntu 12.04 later.

After searching on Ask Ubuntu, I see many users facing the same dilemma. However all the questions about why should we upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 or if the new features will arrive to 12.04 at some point in time are closed.

Why is this being done? Wouldn't it be helpful to give advice to those wanting to decide if they should stick to Ubuntu 12.04 or upgrade?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are not really questions about the the process of upgrading or a user going through the upgrade process.

The questions you are talking about are likely something like "Why should I upgrade" or "Will I have a problem upgrading with XX Computer or Graphics Card" These types of questions fit firmly into this statement listed on the FAQ:

"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems *that you face*. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

And no, new "features" from 12.10 will not be implemented in 12.04, that is the whole reason it is "Latest Stable". That is why those types of questions are closed.

Comment: I see, in fact it is not a pratical question. Anyway I think most of these questions are made because Ubuntu users really want to try the new features but don't want to give up stability. Others have doubts about the new unified Unity. I recently got informed that new Unity makes use of CPU to work on machines without 3D support. This makes Ubuntu sluggish. That topic should be better explained on Ubuntu homepage, where we can't find minimum requirements, so people with no 3D support should be aware that perhaps they shouldn't upgrade (if it is to install another DE, what's the point really).

Comment: True, I myself am disappointed about unity-2d being gone, as I used the launcher in Xubuntu in 12.04. I wonder if we have a master question or Canonical question for these types of changes, to point users towards. Here was one I found about back-porting, http://askubuntu.com/questions/193786/will-the-new-technologies-in-12-10-be-backported-to-12-04 , here is one kind-of about upgrading http://askubuntu.com/questions/101050/should-i-update-to-an-lts-release , here is a how to upgrade , http://askubuntu.com/questions/203301/how-to-safely-upgrade-from-ubuntu-12-04-to-12-10

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking for some questions like that.